# Eclipse breakpoint not binding to corrcect binaries

Tags: java, eclipse, project, breakpoints

Using Eclipse 4.7.3a or 4.8.0 (tried updating to see if that would fix it).

Due to certain circumstances, I have a project that depends on another project.

`Project A` includes `Project B` in its build path.

Assume the project structures are as follows:

```
Project B:
    com.foo.bar.MyClassToOverwrite
    com.foo.bar.MyClassToInherit

Project A:  
    com.foo.bar.MyClassToOverrwrite
```

`Project A` is meant to inherit most of its code from `Project B`, but overwrite some code, in this case it will overwrite `com.foo.bar.MyClassToOverrwrite`.

`MyClassToInherit` calls `MyClassToOverrwrite` (either from `Project A` or `Project B`)

I run `Project A - MyClassToInherit` and it correctly calls `Project A - MyClassToOverrwrite`.

However, I put a breakpoint in `Project A - MyClassToOverrwrite` but it is never triggered.

If I put a breakpoint in `Project B - MyClassToOverrwrite` and run `Project A - MyClassToInherit` which calls `Project A - MyClassToOverrwrite` **it seems to hit the breakpoint that is placed in `Project B` but pause on the nearest line in `Project A`...**

I have ensured that the build path order of `Project A` has `Project A` coming before `Project B`, so that the `Project A` resources will be used rather than the `Project B` resources of the same qualified name.

Other than including one Project in another, I have tried the linked source directory method of sharing project resources, but am still running into the same issue of not hitting breakpoints in the inheriting project.

Breakpoints have worked normally for quite a while. We only ran into this issue yesterday and are not quite sure what changed.

Do you know what might have changed or any places I should look to tell what changed? Do you have any suggestions for a workaround?

Thank you for your time.

If you have any questions please ask, I'll be checking replies on and off tomorrow.

Comment: Can you avoid naming them the same and use a proper type hierarchy or Interface+implementor setup?

Comment: Can not avoid naming them the same. Project A and B are essentially the same project, except that A introduces some differences and overwrites parts of B; We keep B to support legacy, but make additions in A, we will sometimes make fixes to B that will carry forward to A. Perhaps it would be best to have all the code in one project and leave the legacy stuff to version control with tags for each version change, but that might be for later.. For now I still need to make these breakpoints attach to the proper binaries.

Comment: If B and A are essentially two development branches, why are there ANY dependencies between them?  If there are, can you factor them out to a new module on which A and B both depend?  You've painted yourself into a corner here and _some_ restructuring will be required.

Comment: @JimGarrison It's more like 1.5 branches, I know its a pretty wonky setup. If I extracted the shared files into C then I'd have B+C and A+C, but B and A would still have files with the same qnames and might *still have the same breakpoint binding issue*. I have considered refactoring, but we should soon be able to just drop project B and incorporate its remains into A, so I don't think it would be worth the effort. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion about where to set breakpoints has been a known problem for many years.  The underlying confusion relates to having congruent hierarchies.  I first reported
it in 2005, but it's older than that. 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=96051

They've made various attempts to fix the problem but have not succeeded.

Comment: In the related [`bug 5188`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5188#c85), the suggestion to turn *off* `Java -> Debug - Do not install breakpoints from unrelated projects` solved my problem well enough. Though the heart of the problem may be the project structure, at least now I can hit breakpoints again. Thank you!